# ListView Overlap onto Adjacent Item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using a listview, merged together with MergeAdapter and I'm trying to set it up for using StickyListHeaders how I want. Here's how the merged ListView is set up:

ImageView as the first element.

RelativeLayout containing an ImageView and TextView as the second element.

ListView items populated from an adapter.

In the second list item, the height of the ImageView has to be taller than the height of the TextView. But I want the list item height to match the TextView height instead of the ImageView (a fixed height instead of wrap_content). That way, the ImageView from the second list item would ideally overlap onto the ImageView of the first list item.

I've tried messing around with transparency, setting the layout height, and a couple other things but I can't get it to work. Is this just too complicated to happen, or am I missing something? Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way that might not be the simplest but it works. I just put half of the ImageView in each of the list items and cropped the source image to fit.